# Pagination asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, pagination

Is it possible to create simple pagination in MVC 4 with no use of database. I am using SolrNet to return results from my data in server, that's why I don't have database.

So, I whant to create free web site for my users for quick review of data transaction (is mail delivered, etc.). There I have my database, but for fast review of status I am using Solr that is why I don't have database.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap solr results in IEnumerable and pass them to WebGrid:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx